# How do I invite users to my session using Multipeer Connectivity framework?

Tags: ios, swift, multipeer-connectivity

In `viewDidLoad` I setup my session:

```
    peerID = MCPeerID(displayName: UIDevice.current.name)
    mcSession = MCSession(peer: peerID, securityIdentity: nil, encryptionPreference: .required)
    mcSession.delegate = self
    mcAdvertiserAssistant = MCAdvertiserAssistant(serviceType: "hws-kb", discoveryInfo: nil, session: mcSession)
```

and have four actions:

```
func startHosting() {
    mcAdvertiserAssistant.start() //run the session
}
func endHosting() {
    mcAdvertiserAssistant.stop() //stop the session
}
func joinSession() {
    let mcBrowser = MCBrowserViewController(serviceType: "hws-kb", session: mcSession)
    mcBrowser.delegate = self
    present(mcBrowser, animated: true) //join me to active session
}
func leaveSession() {
    mcSession.disconnect() //leave me from active session
}

//how do Invite others to my session?
```

The above way all I can control is to accept or decline when someone wants to connect. But I would like to personally send invitations to the users and not allow the others to join without my invitation. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible as per my knowledge. The invitation goes to all near peers. in this framework, connection establishment is automatically happens when advertise starts. You will have much control while sending data as session object holds all connectedPeers.

And, below notes might help you.

1. in game app, create one admin using browser object and multiple participants using advertiser object.
2. create display name using uuid like let displayName = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString
3. one session holds 8 peers only. if you have more that 8 participants, follow below.

   ```
   func browser(_ browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser, foundPeer peerID: MCPeerID, withDiscoveryInfo info: [String : String]?) {
   let filteredSessions = adminSessions.filter { (session) -> Bool in
       return session.connectedPeers.count != kMCSessionMaximumNumberOfPeers
   }
   if filteredSessions.count == 0 {
       let session =  getNewSession()
       adminSessions.append(session)
       adminBrowser.invitePeer(peerID, to: session, withContext: nil, timeout: 60)
   } else {
       let activeSession = filteredSessions[filteredSessions.count-1]
       adminBrowser.invitePeer(peerID, to: activeSession, withContext: nil, timeout: 60)
   } }
   ```